# PermCheck Codility Scala solution

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, scala

first of all. I am aware this question has been asked a lot. It is regarding the PermCheck lesson of the codility web page. The link can be found here: https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/perm_check/

The reason for my question is quite simple, it is failing the performance check stating the following: Detected time complexity: O(N ** 2).

If you look into my code, I am using a HashSet and I recursively iterate through the array only once. Therefore, I cannot understand where the time complexity O(N^2) is coming from. Moreover, I have seen in the answer already people saying they have used a "For" and "HashSet" and get 100%.

Could it be it also takes into account space complexity but it's a misleading error?

```
def permCheck(a: Array[Int]): Int = {
   def maxAndHash(a: Array[Int], hash: HashSet[Int], max: Int, acc: Int): Option[(Int, Int)] = a match {
  case Array() => Some((max, acc))
  case _ => {
    val head = a.head
    if (hash.contains(head)) None
    else maxAndHash(a.tail, hash + head, if (max < head) head else max, acc + 1)
  }
}

maxAndHash(a, HashSet[Int](), Int.MinValue, 0) match {
  case None => 0
  case Some((max, acc)) => if (acc == max) 1 else 0
  }
}
```

Comment: `a.tail` for arrays has linear complexity. So overall complexity could be square.

Comment: @simpadjo Oh true, I just check. I assumed wrongly it had the same performance as a list. Should I delete the question then?

Comment: For recursive algorithms with a `head / tail` fashion, you should always use **List**, which is the best _(only?)_ collection designed for being efficient in such cases. If using an **Array**, it would be better to just use a loop by index.